# Create a date from Year and Month on a Select query

Tags: python, sql, vertica

I'm working on Vertica

I have a problem, looking really easy, but I can't find a way to figure it out.

From a query, I can get 2 fields "Month" and "Year". What I want is to automatically select another field, Date, that I'd build being '01/Month/Year' (as the sql Date format). The goal is :

**What I have**

```
SELECT MONTH, YEAR FROM MyTable
```

`Output` :

```
01   2020
11   2019
09   2021
```

**What I want**

```
SELECT MONTH, YEAR, *answer* FROM MyTable
```

`Output` :

```
01   2020   01-01-2020
11   2019   01-11-2019
09   2021   01-09-2021
```

Sorry, it looks like really dumb and easy, but I didn't find any good way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string operations to build dates, you can mess up things considerably:
Today could be: `16.07.2021` or `07/16/2021`, or also `2021-07-16`, and, in France, for example: `16/07/2021` . Then, you could also left-trim the zeroes - or have 'July' instead of 07 ....

Try:

```
WITH
my_table (mth,yr) AS (
            SELECT  1, 2020
  UNION ALL SELECT 11, 2019
  UNION ALL SELECT  9, 2021
)
SELECT
  yr
, mth
, ADD_MONTHS(DATE '0001-01-01',(yr-1)*12+(mth-1)) AS firstofmonth
FROM my_table
ORDER BY 1,2;
  yr  | mth | firstofmonth 
------+-----+--------------
 2019 |  11 | 2019-11-01
 2020 |   1 | 2020-01-01
 2021 |   9 | 2021-09-01
```

Comment: That's a way better answer than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way doing that :

```
SELECT MONTH, YEAR, CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR, '-'), CONCAT(MONTH, '-01')) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT [MONTH], [YEAR], CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('01-',[MONTH]),'-'),[YEAR]) AS [DATE] 
FROM MyTable
```

Output will be:

```
| MONTH | YEAR |  DATE      |
|-------|------|------------|
|  01   | 2020 | 01-01-2020 |
|  11   | 2019 | 01-11-2019 |
|  09   | 2021 | 01-09-2021 |
```